# Call parent component function from child in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a simple component in React.JS which displays a list of items, then the user can select an item from the list. I am trying to handle the clicks on the list-items by handing down a function from the parent component to the child, so it can notify the parent when it was clicked and the parent can update the selected item. For some reason the function from the child component is not calling the parent function properly as it never gets to the point to write to the console ... I guess it must something to do with binds, but I literally tried every combination possible to make it work.

Tbh, I don't even understand why I have to use "clicked={()=>this.clickedSub}" in the parent component when I already used bind in the constructor, but I guess I don't have to understand everything XD

```
var months = [
    'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'
];

class SubItem extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);       
         this.clickedMe = this.clickedMe.bind(this);
   }

    clickedMe () {
        let i = this.props.id;
        console.log("from child: "+i);
        this.props.clicked(i);
    }

    render () {
        if (this.props.isSelected) return <a href="#" className="selected" onClick={this.clickedMe}>{this.props.text}</a>;
                else return <a href="#" onClick={this.clickedMe}>{this.props.text}</a>;
    }
}

class SideMenu extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selected: 0,
            open: true
    };

    this.clickedHead = this.clickedHead.bind(this);
    this.clickedSub = this.clickedSub.bind(this);
}

clickedHead () {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
}

clickedSub(i) {
    console.log("from parent:"+i);
    this.setState({
      selected: i
    });
}

render() {

        let sel = this.state.selected;
        var sublist = this.props.subitems.map(function (item, index){
            if (index==sel) return <SubItem text={item} isSelected={true} id={index} clicked={()=>this.clickedSub}/>;
            else return <SubItem text={item} isSelected={false} id={index} clicked={()=>this.clickedSub}/>;
            });

    if (this.state.open) return (
      <div className="side_menu">
                <div className="menu_item open">
                    <div className="header" onClick={this.clickedHead}>{this.props.header}</div>
                    <div className="sub_items">
                        {sublist}
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
    );
        else return(
      <div className="side_menu">
                <div className="menu_item open">
                    <div className="header" onClick={this.clickedHead}>{this.props.header}</div>
                    <div className="sub_items"></div>
                </div>
      </div>        
        );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SideMenu header="Month" subitems={months}/>,
  document.getElementById('menu')
);
```

See the Pen [vertical collapsible side-menu](https://codepen.io/ize8/pen/yoLGPQ/) by Ize8 on CodePen.

Comment: what is the function you pass down to the child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I struggled with this one for a little while. You have to be really careful when you do NOT use es6 in react. Arrow functions are your friend, and generally just make more sense.

This is where all your trouble is coming from:

```
var sublist = this.props.subitems.map(function (item, index){
        if (index==sel) return <SubItem text={item} isSelected={true} id={index} clicked={()=>this.clickedSub}/>;
        else return <SubItem text={item} isSelected={false} id={index} clicked={()=>this.clickedSub}/>;
        });
```

You want to use arrow functions here because you're messing with the scope. You can pass down the function as intended, and you do not have to do this `clicked={() => this.clickedSub}` syntax which is confusing.

```
var sublist = this.props.subitems.map((item, index) => {
        if (index==sel) return <SubItem text={item} isSelected={true} id={index} clicked={this.clickedSub}/>;
        else return <SubItem text={item} isSelected={false} id={index} clicked={this.clickedSub}/>;
        });
```

This will pass down your function as intended, but you have some other issues with your code. It causes an infinite loop, but I'll let you implement this and work through it.

Comment: Thanks, eventually I figured it out! ...but I didn't find any infinite loop :P
just used the arrow function properly as you suggested, and kept the binds in the constructors too ... its a bit unclear why to have to use them both as I'd have thought the arrow function takes care of the binding, but it works!

Comment: ignore that, the arrow function in the map ensures that "this" refers to the component and the binds in constructor makes the "this" work properly in the function ... I just needed my morning coffee XD

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you don't wont to have `.bind(this)` in constructor use an `arrow function`

```
clickedSub(i){} it is clickedSub = (i)=>{}
```

Now. I don't get what function you pass to the children. but I will show you an example.

```
class Parent extends Component {

  constructor() {...}

  parentFunction = () => {
    console.log('This will be called when we click `a` tag in Child component');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child funct = {this.parentFunction}/>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.func();
  }

  render() {
    return(
       <a onClick={this.handleClick}> Click me </a>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason I get an error message from codepen with this syntax :(